# Accept Additional Value Using API Query

Tags: php, api

Here's an API query I've tracked down in a custom app built by another company with no documentation that's out of my skill set but well within one of yours.

The purpose is to find any items with a 'Category' equal to 'Important'.

It would be great to also return items with a 'Category' equal to '3M CGS' as well as 'Important'.

**HERE'S THE WORKING CODE FOR THE IMPORTANT CATEGORY**

```
//List:  Calendar, CATEGORY=IMPORTANT

var queryImportantDept = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Calendar')/Items?$select,FileRef=*&$orderby=EventDate%20asc&$top=10&$filter=Category%20eq%20%27Important%27"; 

$.ajax({ url: queryImportantDept, method: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, success: onQuerySuccessDeptImportantDates, error: onQueryErrorDeptImportantDates});
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up

Comment: Is there more information I need to provide for help with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ODATA you can easily combine filter expressions. So in your case the following expression

```
$filter=Category%20eq%20%27Important%27
```

will can be logically combined with `and` to this expression:

```
$filter=Category%20eq%20%27Important%27%20and%20Category%20eq%20%273M%20CGS%27%20
```

Visually more appealing might be this form:

```
$filter=Category eq 'Important' and Category eq '3M CGS'
```

If you want to return an entity, if `Category` is *either* `Important` *or* `3M CGS` (or both) you can use this form:

```
$filter=Category eq 'Important' or Category eq '3M CGS'
```

You can also put in brackets if you have more complex scenarios or prefer this for readabilty:

```
$filter=(Category eq 'Important') and (Category eq '3M CGS')
```

Don't forget to UrlEncode it if your framework is not doing this already.

For more information about ODATA query options, you can have a look at http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/ (this is v3, use the appropriate version depending on the system you are talking to).

Comment: Thanks for this very well detailed explanation. I will start looking into ODATA as a possible solution for a number of similar issues :)